# How to plot frequency from a CSV Column in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a CSV file with columns:  `created_at, hashtags, media, urls, favorite_count`. 
I would like to plot the frequency of hashtags. 
To read the CSV file I used pandas (but I would like also to show/list the result):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/path/file',delimiter=",")
```

Then, to plot the frequency of hashtags in the file, I used

```
 plt.plot(df["hashtags"])
 plt.show()
```

but I received the error: "nan is not a string".
Any suggestion on how to plot the column and visualise the results as both plot and pretty table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df.dropna()
df.reset_index(drop = True)

plt.plot(df["Column1"], df["Column1"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Val - The issue is that you have NaN (Not a Number) values in your column that need to be removed or changed. The code provided removes any NaN out of the df and resets the index. I hope that helps.!